# Management of .eml files when using an external editor in Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird, text-editors

I just started using the external editor (1.0) feature for Thunderbird on OS X. To send a message you have to save the message contents and then close the editor.

Does the external editor app automatically delete the .eml files that are saved (in /tmp/ for Mac) after a time, or is it up to the user to delete them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally this is done by the mail program – it created the .eml file in the first place, so it should clean up too. (I haven't used such a feature in Thunderbird, though.)

The editor does not know the difference between "normal" and "temporary" files.

Comment: Thunderbird does retrieve text from the temporary file upon closing emacs so it should be aware... but in this case I guess the answer is "no".